# Properly migrating app+data backup from one phone to another with a broken digitizer

Tags: nexus-4, nexus-5, restore, titanium-backup

I have just cracked my Nexus 4 screen, which seemingly has completely destroyed the digitizer, as I cannot interface with my screen anymore.

Luckily, I had a TB schedule that ran on my nexus 4 every day, which backed my apps+data and pushed to box cloud storage. So, what I did with my new nexus 5 is I went through the unlock, root, and rom flashing process. Then, I installed Titanium Backup and synced from my box folder, which I confirmed with ES that all of the app/data that I need is indeed there (apks, .properties files).

The problem that I am encountering is that my "restore missing apps + data" does not show many of the applications that I need to restore. I am not really sure why this could happen, unless maybe TB is noting the fact that the apps state that the device is "Nexus 4" in the properties file? (probably not, all of them do) I have attempted to refresh TB, which did cause some more apps to appear, but I still am missing a huge chunk of applications. To further complicate matters, when I go to my "delete backups for uninstalled applications" menu, I see a couple of the missing applications ( but not all )... only they seem to be missing icons and do not have fully resolved application names ( instead listing their com.x.x.x package names).

I'm quite confused.

**What I'm trying now :** I have a computer that (hopefully) has been auth'd for ADB access, so I'll try to pull the TB folder from my actual phone and see if I can overwrite the files and restore them that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to be able to use ADB's ability to simulate touch input to pair a bluetooth mouse to my phone, but it does not seem like this is going to be possible because I am running 4.2+ which requires RSA fingerprint authentication... which none of my computers have permission for.

I will order a USB 3-way Y cable and [use a hack version of USB OTG](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/orig-development/usb-otg-externally-powered-usb-otg-t2181820) to plug in a physical mouse. I can do this because I can use ADB through fastboot to temporarily boot a non-touch CWM recovery, then use ADB to push the modified kernel img and flash using the non-touch interface, which should then hopefully boot up. Since I'm on CM10.2 I already know Franco Kernel causes soft-brick, so hopefully the modified OTG stock kernel does not cause soft-brick. Once I have the phone fully booted, it should just be a matter of connecting a power source and pointing device to interface with my device.